# Why am I not getting any crystal?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

In the first missions of the Necropolis campaign, I have a crystal mine that says it produces one crystal per day, but my total daily crystal income is zero. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you actually own it? If there's an enemy-controlled (or even *neutral*-controlled fort / town in the area, all of the mine's production will go to them, unless you've got a hero constantly sitting on top of the mine.

What week is it? Certain weeks can cause resource or creature surplus / shortfalls.

Has an enemy hero plundered / sabotaged a mine? That could prevent production also.

There are also occasions were, sporadically, Crystal production drops to zero due to bugs. If none of the above, you might try reloading the game, which will cause crystal production to resume if it has stopped from the bug.

Comment: I am sure that I own it. I captured it, I own the nearby fort, and when I right click it shows up with my colors even if I am not occupying it.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the week I was in decreased resource income. Before this I did not even know there were any weeks like that.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - Yeah, there are also weeks that increase it.

Comment: Is there anything else that could cause this?  I am also on the first Necropolis mission, and the same crystal mine is not generating anything.  I've gone through two weeks of turns (14) and neither week had anything to do with resource production and I have yet to see a single crystal be added to my kingdom.

Comment: @JasonBerkan - are you sure you actually control the mine?

Comment: @RavenDreamer - yes.  Looks like a bug, as upon saving / restoring, I started receiving the 1 crystal per day.

Comment: Me too, But I think it a game bug because when I reloading it reset and re-income again.

Comment: Can you include the reloading/resetting in the answer please. I missed that teeny detail when looking for a fix to this bug

Answer (score 7):

I found what caused my problem: I was in the week of festivals, which cuts all resource income in half. Since I usually only had an income of one crystal per day, the festival cut it down to zero per day.

Answer (score 2):

I played a game with a friend, and both of us had severely slashed incomes of all resources. This happened week after week, until I restarted from an autosave to see if that solved it. Sure enough,my crystal income went from 0 to 2 and everything else virtually doubled!

Looks like it's  some kind of weird bug.:s It really makes it hard to develop your towns. :s

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but fortunately I spotted it quickly and loaded from the autosave. It never happened again.